# How do I use punctuation in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, punctuation

I can use regular punctuation like - and * but what if I want to use something more exotic, like a star or something else like the ones I find in Pages. I tried a simple copy paste of pages punctuations, but it didn't work. Do I need to program in the punctuations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree) of the Firebase Documentation, the characters that you can use for keys have the following rule :-

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a
>   maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII
>   control characters 0-31 or 127.